# Messages in MSMQ queue not being read by Rebus

Tags: .net, msmq, rebus

I'm trying to debug an application where it gets into a state where the MSMQ queue is building up but the messages aren't being handled anymore.

My understanding of Rebus/MSMQ is very basic (I've inherited this application with original developers well and truly gone).

I want to understand why Rebus, when I restart the application, doesn't read the messages in the queue that currently exist? My understand is that Rebus is driven by an event at the time the message is placed in the queue and if the application is in a buggy state then these messages will get placed in the queue and never handled.

I've been reading the documentation for Rebus and can't seem to find much more information than just the pipeline explanations.

There is too much code in this application to really post here, but the application is using Rebus.Ninject version 0.80.1 (this is an old application).

I'll edit to include any information people need.

EDIT:

```
var bus = Configure.With(new NinjectContainerAdapter(context.Kernel))
    .Logging(l => l.NLog())
    .Transport(t => t.UseMsmq(sourceQueue, errorQueue))
    .MessageOwnership(d => d.Use(new CustomBusMessageOwnership(uowFactory)))
    .Serialization(s => s.UseCustomJsonSerialization())
    .CreateBus()
    .Start(numWorkers);
```

The UseCustomJsonSerialization method just sets the encoding to UTF8 and SerializeEnumAsStrings to true.

EDIT 2:
FINALLY got a chance to look into this again. I created an automatic crash dump of one of our installs that seems to fail more often than the others.

Here is the stack trace from WinDbg:

```
00000000 00000001 mscorlib_ni!System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod+0x2
0763ee84 6ef6f561 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal+0xa1
0763eea8 6ef6f096 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke+0x66
0763eedc 6ef640b6 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke+0x16
0763eee8 07355234 UNKNOWN!Rebus.Bus.Worker+_DoTry_d__2b.MoveNext+0x57c
0763efa4 07354c73 mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[[Rebus.Bus.Worker+_DoTry_d__2b,_Rebus]]+0x43
0763eff8 07354c0a UNKNOWN!Rebus.Bus.Worker.DoTry+0x6a
0763f074 073546f2 UNKNOWN!Rebus.Bus.Worker+_TryProcessIncomingMessage_d__23.MoveNext+0x62
0763f0ac 0735424b mscorlib_ni!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncVoidMethodBuilder.Start[[Rebus.Bus.Worker+_TryProcessIncomingMessage_d__23,_Rebus]]+0x43
0763f100 073541f0 UNKNOWN!Rebus.Bus.Worker.TryProcessIncomingMessage+0x40
0763f144 07353ffe UNKNOWN!Rebus.Bus.Worker.MainLoop+0x5e
0763f174 6ef66d11 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context+0x9d
0763f180 6ef866ea mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal+0xea
0763f1f0 6ef865f6 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x16
0763f204 6ef865b1 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x41
0763f21c 6ef66c6c mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart+0x44
```

Comment: When I hear about symptoms like this, I have often found out that the "error" was caused by the bus being disposed too quickly.  Could you show me how the receiving bus is configured?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the configuration of the receiving bus

Comment: When is the Ninject container disposed?

Comment: There is a BusService class inherting from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase. The Stop method is overwritten:
    protected override void Stop()
        {
            _bus.Dispose();
            base.Stop();
        }

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard for me to see what's wrong with this program. Also, it's a pretty old version of Rebus that's being used (although I don't think that's the problem). Could you maybe show some more code?

Comment: I'm going to try and recreate using some integration tests today to narrow down where the issue is. We're having a hard time reproducing this, it only seems to happen when we get a large number of messages being put into the queue in quick fashion. The implementation seems pretty solid (we've got 100+ clients using this and only a handful of busier customers ever run into this, although it does happen often enough to have made it's way back to a dev task to fix). I'll update the question when I have more information or a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've enabled trace logging on the production server for a client where we get these issues. I'll update the question when I get something worthwhile

Comment: Hi @berniefitz, did you figure something out?

Comment: Seems like the app is crashing due to a memory exception and therefore not reading the messages from the queue. Still trying to determine exactly what is going on

Comment: Ah, ok – is it a Windows Service? In that case, you can configure it to automatically be restarted after it crashes...

Comment: Yeah it is a windows service, but it’s not completely stopping so auto restart isn’t kicking in. I’m trying to do some profiling to see what’s going on. I think it’s not handling a rest request to a GIS server properly. I will update when I get to the bottom of this. May take some time though